# jQuery remove text from h1

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have to build a shoppinglist where I can add and delete lists.
On the right side there is the currently opened list with the list headline.
When deleting a list, the headline should disappear, but it doesn´t, neither with empty(), nor remove() or text(' ').

I just edited the post so you can see the whole HTML code

```
HTML:           
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div id="shoppinglist">
                    <div class="header left">
                        <h2>Listen</h2>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus newList" ></i>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list lists">
                        <!-- -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="header right">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
                    <img src="img/profile.png" alt="profilbild">
                </div>
                <div id="listbody">
                    <div class="listheader">
                        <!--<h1>List 1</h1>-->
                    </div>
                    <div id="listitems">
                        <div class="items_container">
                            <!-- -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div id="categorylist">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h2>Kategorien</h2>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list categories">
                        <!-- -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="header">
                    <input placeholder="Was willst du Einkaufen?" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div id="categoryitems">
                    <div class="items_container">
                        <!-- -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="producthover_container">
            <div id='producthover'>
                <div id='producthover_icon'>
                    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i>
                </div>
                <div id='producthover_detail'>
                    <span>Details <br> hinzufügen</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


list.js:   
printHeader(){
     $(".listheader").empty();
     $(".listheader").append("<h1 class='h1header'>" + this.name + "</h1>");
}


shoppinglist.js:
$(".lists").on("click","i",(e) =>{
    let r = confirm("Delete?");
    if(r) {
       $(".h1header").remove();
       $(e.target).parent().remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: None of the elements you show have a class named `h1header`. I guess the `i` and `.lists` elements are elsewhere?

Comment: Well for the class with `h1header` I guess `printheader` in `list.js` needs to get executed.  But yeah, where are the list items?

Comment: Sorry, now you can see all the html elements

Answer (score 0):

you have to Remove it from the parent node. like this:

```
var child = $(".h1header");
$(".listheader").removeChild(child);
```

or you will have to create a function that does this when given a child node

Comment: This gets me the error:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeChild is not a function
    at HTMLElement.$.on (shoppinglist.js:78)
    at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLUListElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: that's because you don't have any elements with the class `h1header` double check the order of the operations being done.  you may need to add an if/then statement on the existence of a header with the class `h1header`